# Intento redireccionar con outcome en primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, login

Tengo el archivo `index.xhtml` y `login.xhtml`.

En `index.xhtml` hay un `menuItem` que redirecciona a login.xhtml con ayuda del archivo:

faces-config.xml.

Cuando hago click, me redirecciona a `login.xhtml` y todos los métodos a los que llaman los botones se inicializan sin necesidad de click los botones.

**index.xhtml**:

```
<p:menuitem value="#{es_bundle.IniciarSesion}" outcome="login"/>`.
```

**login.xhtml**:

El problema lo da el botón de iniciar sesión, que lanza el método `login()` sin dar click al botón.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Iniciar sesión | AGRUPADOS</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/jsfcrud.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
     <p:growl id="growl" life="3000" />   
<h:panelGroup id="display">
<p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{userController.selected != null}" >
<p:outputLabel value="Usuario" for="username" />
<p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}"/>
<p:outputLabel value="Contraseña" for="password" />
<p:password id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}"/>
</p:panelGrid>
<p:button value="#{es_bundle.IniciarSesion}" outcome="#
 {loginBean.login()}"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="No tienes cuenta? " />
                <p:button value="Registrarse" outcome="register"/>
                <p:button value="No iniciar sesión" outcome="index"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

No creo que haga falta poner el codigo del metodo login. Lo que hace es comprobar que el usuario esta en la base de datos y, según el rol del usuario, devuelve un rol o otro que redirecciona al usuario a x.xhtml.

Si cambio el boton de Iniciar sesión por un `<p:commandButton action="#{loginBean.login()}"` si que funciona, pero no cambia el link de la pagina sin usar outcome, así que si redirecciona y no cambia el link, al recargar la pagina vuelve a la pagina de login.

Espero no haberme explicado demasiado mal, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes poner la primer parte del xhtml del login para ver que eventos estas llamando cuando inicia la pagina

Comment: ¿No tendrás en tu controller una **propíedad** llamada login?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que esta sucediendo es que al momento de renderizar el componente button a html, jsf necesita saber cuanto vale la propiedad outcome. Y como esa propiedad esta linkeada a tu bean, invoca al método login para poder saber cual es el valor.

Cambiar a action es la mejor solución me parece. No se modifica la url porque estas realizando un forward en lugar de un redirect. [Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w) hay una buena explicación sobre esto último.

Answer (score 0):

Hola en tu método login si el usuario es válido y de acuerdo a los roles debes hacer un return  "index?faces-redirect=true"; de este modo cambiará la  URL

Y el commandbutton debe llamar al método login mediante action